# Retrofit 504 Unsatisfiable Request (only-if-cached)

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp, http-caching

I'm trying to use Caching using Retrofit and OkHttp.

I'm adding this interceptor to OkHttp builder like.

```
  @Provides
  @Singleton
  @TokenHttpClient
  internal fun provideTokenOkHttpClient(
          @BaseHttpClient okHttpClient: OkHttpClient,
          cacheInterceptor: NetworkCacheInterceptor): OkHttpClient {
    return okHttpClient.newBuilder()
            .addInterceptor(cacheInterceptor)
            .build()
```

And the interceptor looks like this:

```
class NetworkCacheInterceptor(val context: Context): Interceptor {

  @Throws(IOException::class)
  override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {

    var response = chain.request()


    response = if (hasNetwork(context))

      response.newBuilder()
        .removeHeader("Pragma")
        .removeHeader("Cache-Control")
        .header("Cache-Control",
          "public, max-age=${CacheControl.Builder().maxAge(30, TimeUnit.DAYS).build()}")
        .build()
    else {

      response.newBuilder()
        .removeHeader("Pragma")
        .removeHeader("Cache-Control")
        .header("Cache-Control",
          "public, only-if-cached, max-stale=${CacheControl.Builder().maxAge(30, TimeUnit.DAYS).build()}")
        .cacheControl(CacheControl.FORCE_CACHE)
        .build()

      response
    }
    return chain.proceed(response)
  }

}
```

This way of implementation it's saving responses into `cache` folder. But it's not working when offline. I've tired to separate interceptors and add the caching as networkInterceptor and the offline interceptor as normal interceptor but it didn't work. On this case no cache was saved.

When I check cached files I see these headers:

```
GET
0
HTTP/1.1 200 
15
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: value
Cache-Control: no-cache
ETag: "01785cb0981d28aa96d58e491dbd6873e"
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Referrer-Policy: no-referrer
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Date: Tue, 21 May 2019 07:50:51 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Encoding: gzip
OkHttp-Sent-Millis: 1558425050896
OkHttp-Received-Millis: 1558425050928
```

Any idea? What I'm missing?